# Why is my font being applied to HTML from CSS but color and text decoration isn't?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navbar. I'm trying to remove the text decoration from the nav links. However, even though my "font-family" of "Roboto" is being applied, "color" and "text-decoration" isn't. Please find my code below

```css
li {
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303133;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Hello">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
            <nav class="navlinks"> 
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a>
 
            </ul>
        </nav>
               
      
   </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` tags have their own styling applied by the browser so they actually look like **links**, so you usually need to target them directly to apply your own styles.

Font properties are usually inherited in the browser styles, so they style links like:

```
a {
   font-size: inherit;
   font-family: inherit;
}
```

Or similar, so they will apply the font properties you specify on parent elements, but the color and text decoration are not inherited, they usually have a specific blue color and `underline` decoration; since they aren't inheriting them from the parent, you need to target the `<a>` tag element directly to override these values;

```css
li a{
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303133;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Hello">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
            <nav class="navlinks"> 
                <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a>
 
            </ul>
        </nav>
               
      
   </header>
```

Comment: Moreover you can check in developer tab incase any other css overwrites your css file.

Comment: Correct, but unless you are using something to reset the CSS of the page like normalize.css, is pretty much guaranteed you'll just have to target the anchor tags directly to apply styles to links :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Yes. That's true though.

Comment: @FlashBangKev please mark answers that answered your question as accepted, this will not leave the question hanging as "unanswered" and will reward the person who helped you with reputation points.